# React Native ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\kemal\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\kemal\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\kemal\OneDrive\Masa�st�\Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\kemal\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v19.0.0

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

B

when ı write run npm android

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.